# Redirect audio input and output with Zoom and Telegram

Tags: audio

On my Windows 10 machine I join to a Zoom meeting and talk to persons A and B and at the same time do a Telegram call and talk to person C. Is there a way to redirect audio input and output to make person C hear my voice and voices of A and B, but make A and B hear only my voice?

Can these settings help?

[image]

(it is not clear why there is no Zoom and Telegram)

Comment: Easiest is to use the speakers in the zoom call and make the telegram call on your phone

Comment: @1NN no it is not an option, need to share the screen with telegram

Comment: You could possibly use [VB-AUDIO Software](https://vb-audio.com/) to connect the audio inputs and outputs of each software in a way that fulfills the demand.

Comment: @harrymc I need to use Zoom and Telegram.

Comment: VB-AUDIO might be a solution.

Comment: @harrymc it can help with Zoom and Telegram, right?

Comment: It can help with almost any application, but might need some learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a tool to mix the output from Zoom together with your microphone (I propose OBS for that), and then feed that mix as a "Microphone" to Telegram (I propose Virtual Audio Cable for that).

- Install [OBS](https://obsproject.com/)
- Install [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/)
- Let's say in Zoom you are using Speakers1 and Mic1
- In OBS, add Mic1 as Audio Input ([see tutorial](https://www.alphr.com/add-audio-source-obs/)), and activate monitoring for it.
- In OBS, add the Zoom app as Audio Input (Zoom must be running!) [as described here](https://obsproject.com/kb/application-audio-capture-guide). This feature is in Beta and might not work correctly. Activate monitoring.
- For the next step, I adapt from [this thread](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-virtual-microphone-in-obs.141305/):

> in OBS, go to Settings->Audio->Advanced->Monitoring device and set the
> "CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)". Then, go to
> Edit->Advanced Audio Properties and set the "Audio Monitoring" drop
> down list to  "Monitor only", to output the
> corresponding source to the virtual audio device. All sources with
> activated monitoring are mixed to the monitoring device.

- In Telegram, use "CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" as microphone.

You'll have to thoroughly test this on your precise system with your precise software versions, as not everything might work as intended.
Also, you'll need to use headphones, otherwise your mic might capture the sounds from Telegram, and feed them into Zoom.